# Error with Kmeans "Could not find the number of physical cores" in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm running Python 3.8.10 on Windows 7 with 64 bits. I'm trying to run this simple example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],

              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init="auto").fit(X)

kmeans.labels_

kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])

kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

But I'm getting this Warning, and the code doesn't run:

```
Warning (from warnings module):

  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\context.py", line 136

    warnings.warn(

UserWarning: Could not find the number of physical cores for the following reason:

[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Returning the number of logical cores instead. You can silence this warning by setting LOKY_MAX_CPU_COUNT to the number of cores you want to use.

  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\context.py", line 257, in _count_physical_cores

    cpu_info = subprocess.run(

  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in run

    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__

    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child

    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
```

I set: LOKY_MAX_CPU_COUNT to 2, because is the number of cores that my PC has, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone has an idea?